# Imagebutton scaling and 9Patch

Tags: android, imagebutton, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have a relative layout and image buttons that abut each other.
It all fits nicely on a 1280x800 tablet screen.
On a 1024x600 screen it does not fit.
So, I thought that 9Patch might be the solution, but it does not seem to work.
What's wrong and how do I get the layout/buttons to scale up and down automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not seem to work"?

Comment: Please add more information, like code and/or images of your 9patch.

Comment: By "not working" I mean that the size of the imagebutton(s) does not scale down to match the reduced screen size

Answer (score 0):

What I find with 9Patches, is that they are great for scaling up, rather than down. Maybe use a smaller image and it'll scale up.

Also make sure your 9.png is valid, make sure those corners are clear if you did it in paint/photoshop/something.